# ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt not generated in JMeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter-4.0

I am working with JMeter 4.0 and trying to run the record test. Also I have Java 1.8 installed on my machine.

`ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` is not getting generated in the `bin` folder though I get a message that is getting generated. I search my whole disk drive but no where to be found. I tried all the solutions answered for this problem but could not resolve it can some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the issue was using one JDK (Oracle) to run Apache Jmeter, while the keytool that was being used was under another JDK (IBM).

Once I set the keytool to be the same JDK (Oracle) the file `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` was generated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have it generated you need to have a JDK nor a JRE as the keytool utility is used to do it.

So install a JDK and set path to it then test if you have keytool utility available.

Comment: I did set jdk bin in my path , still I see it is not getting generated.

Answer (score 0):

I would  like to update that this was Java issue , I had to uninstall IBM java and install oracle Java , unfortunately I had to completely format my hard disk as IBM java was left in fragments and the certificate issue had come for Jmeter. So I completely formatted my hard disk and installed oracle  Java and the issue resolved.